# Imaginary Matrices in Sympy using MatrixSymbol

Tags: python, sympy

Multiplying  a matrix with the imaginary unit raises an exception, i.e.,

```
import sympy as sy 

M = sy.MatrixSymbol('M', 2, 2)  
print(sy.I * M)
```

raises the exception

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison of non-real I
```

My current workaround is to replace `sy.I` with an `i = sy.Symbol('i')`.
Is there a better way to use the `MatrxixSymbol` together with imaginary expressions?
Thanks.

PS: Conda Python 3.7.6 and Sympy version 1.5.1 is used.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using the code shown. Are you sure you all the necessary code is there?

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Thanks for the pointer. You are right,  the exception only seems to appear when displaying the exception. I added a print statement to the code to make the exception appear.

Comment: This is a bug in SymPy. I've opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18743 for it. The bug only occurs when printing the expression, so you can work around it by avoiding printing the expression.

Comment: @asmeurer I tested the PR https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/18744 and it fixes the problem. If you like, you can make your comment to an answer, to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SymPy. I've opened github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18743 for it. The bug only occurs when printing the expression, so you can work around it by avoiding printing the expression.